# Bad SQL performance for ASP.NET web app

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I have an ASP.NET web app (written in C# with Microsoft VS 2010.) Since it was installed on the SQL Server I got the following reports for the performance stats:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I can't put all of the source code here that is involved -- it's too much to post. So I was wondering, where can I start addressing this issue?

Answer (score 9):

[SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx). You can find out the queries (or stored procs) that are taking the longest to execute and go from there.

Another place to look is to see what kind of queries are being created from the Application (i.e. is it using LINQ to SQL, is it using parametrized queries or stored procs, or are they creating dynamic query strings).

**Update:** In case you're using an Express version of SQL Server, it should be noted that [SP1 of SQL Server 2012 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35579) comes with SQL Management Studio Express that includes the Profiler.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to retrieve the list of slow queries from the SQL Server itself?

Comment: @ahmd0 - Cymen has posted some queries that can be run against SQL Server. Unless yours is the only application querying that database, those queries seem to show the most expensive queries ever run. In profiler you can turn it off/on to see queries being executed at that time.

Comment: @CAbbott Is correct -- you can narrow it down to a specific database by altering the queries but by default it will be everything on the SQL Server instance.

Comment: @CAbbott Is also correct on the "ever run" to a degree -- some of the data falls off and you'll be able to observe this as you make changes and rerun the queries. You can also restart SQL Server to reset them.

Answer (score 4):

I typically use the queries below even when I have the tools as a quick way to get started. The tools are still useful for analyzing a query and lots of other tasks but to get a quick peek into why the server is overloaded it is very helpful.

Helpful query for looking at what columns to index:

```
SELECT TOP 10
[Total Cost] = ROUND(avg_total_user_cost * avg_user_impact * (user_seeks + user_scans),0)
, avg_user_impact
, TableName = statement
, [EqualityUsage] = equality_columns
, [InequalityUsage] = inequality_columns
, [Include Cloumns] = included_columns
FROM sys.dm_db_missing_index_groups g
INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats s
ON s.group_handle = g.index_group_handle
INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_details d
ON d.index_handle = g.index_handle
ORDER BY [Total Cost] DESC;
```

Helpful query for finding expensive queries:

```
SELECT TOP 10 SUBSTRING(qt.TEXT, (qs.statement_start_offset/2)+1,
((CASE qs.statement_end_offset
WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(qt.TEXT)
ELSE qs.statement_end_offset
END - qs.statement_start_offset)/2)+1),
qs.execution_count,
qs.total_logical_reads, qs.last_logical_reads,
qs.total_logical_writes, qs.last_logical_writes,
qs.total_worker_time,
qs.last_worker_time,
qs.total_elapsed_time/1000000 total_elapsed_time_in_S,
qs.last_elapsed_time/1000000 last_elapsed_time_in_S,
qs.last_execution_time,
qp.query_plan
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) qt
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qs.plan_handle) qp
ORDER BY qs.total_logical_reads DESC -- logical reads
-- ORDER BY qs.total_logical_writes DESC -- logical writes
-- ORDER BY qs.total_worker_time DESC -- CPU time
```

Note that lines beginning with `--` are comments so take note of the last three lines of the above query as you can choose by CPU time, logical reads or logical writes.

Note that you have asked about performance in general however your screenshots are all related to locks. Based on that, I'd try to find where you are making these locks in the application. Maybe the duration of the lock/transaction can be reduced?

References:

- [SQL Server: Uncover Hidden Data to Optimize Application Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135978.aspx)
- [SQL SERVER – Find Most Expensive Queries Using DMV](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/05/14/sql-server-find-most-expensive-queries-using-dmv/)

Comment: Here is another "flavor" of the DMV queries : http://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/2011/02/04/five-dmv-queries-that-will-make-you-a-superhero-in-2011/

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I forgot to mention that most of it is concerning SQL locks (stuff like `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT TRANSACTION`.) I'm assuming those happen to be locks, right?

Comment: @ahmd0 I believe so. I would read the [Queries Suffering from Blocking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135978.aspx#S13) section of the first reference. The whole article is actually really useful. You might have overlapping transactions or some other painful thing too (unlikely, but something to look for).